# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: javascript

I have written a small code using index.html and three .js files. It was working fine if i run it through my local. As soon as i uploaded it to github and hosted my webpage and opened it the above error is coming. i am attaching the url of my github page : https://sravya160597.github.io/courseracss/mod4_solution/index.html

please help me if anyone has a solution for this.

Comment: You should add the code of all the files to the question

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at the page source, and comparing to your github repository, it appears that the problem is case sensitivity in github pages (whereas your localhost must be case-insensitive). Both your `SpeakHello.js` and `SpeakGoodBye.js` should start with a lowercase, as follows:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script src="js/speakHello.js"></script>
    <script src="js/speakGoodBye.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
```